# problem in decoding htaccess url rewrite values

Tags: php

i have written a code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category-search/(.*)$ category-search.php?cat_id=$1
```

and my current URL is

www.mydomain.com/category-search/=NA==

Last values (=NA==) is encoded in base64_encode.
But when i m trying to fetch this values in php like...

```
$val=mysql_real_escape_string(base64_decode($_REQUEST['cat_id']));
```

I am getting $val equal to nothing. What is error behind this ?

When i was not rewrite in htaccess this was working well.

Answer (score 1):

`=NA==` is not a valid base64-encoded string (wrong length and invalid character at the beginning). Did you mean `NA64==`? That decodes to `4`.

In case of `=NA==`, base64_decode() would return `false`, which outputs as empty string.

Comment: @Ajay: You're welcome. (btw, if an answer solved your problem, tick its checkmark (on the left) to mark it as accepted)

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you be looking at $_REQUEST['cat_id'] instead of $_REQUEST['sub_cat_id'] as that is what you have called the request parameter in the .htaccess file...

Comment: sorry this is perfect code insted of above..

 $val=mysql_real_escape_string(base64_decode($_REQUEST['cat_id']));